# Soft delete on Parent Entity but Hard delete on Child/Relationship EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities generated Code First in EF Core : `User`, `Project` and `UserProject` (many to many relationship). Up until now I used hard delete on `User`, which essentially cascaded into the relationship.
Is there a way to implement soft deleting on `User` and hard deleting others without having to manually check for isDeleted flag in other relationship where this is referenced?
Is there any way to trigger the OnDelete/OnUpdate with a custom action?
Example : Define OnDelete as updating the isDeletedFlag, case in which I want to perform hard delete / set null on every other entity User is referenced in.

Comment: Why not make everything soft delete? (Every time I've mixed the approaches, I've come to wish later, that I hadn't)

Comment: Would be a good approach, if the project was in planning phase. Initially going with hard delete, the database is already done, relationships, a lot of them and would be a bit painful to update all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ef core triggers. you can define triggers before save changes to your any specific entity with any approach. but it is available only in .net 5 and .net 6

https://github.com/koenbeuk/EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered

https://youtu.be/Gjys0Yebobk